# Find outr which IPs are from program and which IPs are from addons

Tags: networking, iptables, wireshark

I have a program (that legitimately calls authors) and plug-ins that also call authors (not so legitimately). I want to run the vanilla version of a program and collect IPs it is trying to connect. Should be between 100 and 1000 IPs.
Then I want to add one plug-in at a time to find the spy Checking where it calls and blocking access by iptables. What would be the easiest way to do it? Wireshark+IPtables?

GUI is preferred, but not required, as long as I dont have to add 1000 ips to iptables by hand. This is a game with add-ons runing under vmplayer Windows guest.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: There's no automated way to achieve this.

Comment: I think there's a small typo in the comment above - it should probably read:  "There's no automated way to achieve this that I'm aware of" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this come to mind:

1. Run the application under the control of `strace` which logs all system calls, including attempts to connect.

Let's say you want to run `firefox` and see what it connects to:

```
# Start the process under the control of strace, logging only network-related calls:
strace -e trace=network -o network_calls -f firefox

# After finishing working with firefox, print the IPs it tried to communicate with:
grep -o -P '(\d+\.){3}\d+' network_calls | sort -u
```

This can be scripted, for the strace to be running constantly and the logfile being periodically rotated, etc. but the method below is more suitable if you'd like to leave the app running for a longer time and avoid having to write scripts.

2. Run the application as a different user and add iptables rules that match based on the process owner UID and act accordingly.

Example dropping network traffic of a user with UID 5555:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 5555 -j DROP
```

You could replace DROP with LOG, do whatever else you wish, such as throttle connections, select ports you wish to deny, etc.

Add a comment if you'd like me to expand on a specific approach and I should be able to update my answer.

Comment: "Run the application under the control of strace which logs all system calls, including attempts to connect."  Given that "This is a game with add-ons runing under vmplayer Windows guest.", you presumably mean [strace for Windows](http://drmemory.org/strace_for_windows.html).  Solution 2 might work, if "the application" in "Run the application as a different user" refers to VMware Workstation (which is running on Linux) rather than the game (which is running on Windows in a virtual machine).

Comment: I will try the strace and post a new strace specific question in a new thread if I have a problem with it. I think strace solves +iptables solves the problem.

Comment: I will run vmware as a new user with iptables set up for that user.

Comment: @GuyHarris Actually I meant stracing the vmplayer process, not using strace for Windows. But since you mentioned it, I thought: I don't really know how vmware emulates network access. I assumed that it translates network calls made by guest OS to the host OS system calls, which I thought strace would be able to intercept. Is this not how this works?

Comment: "I assumed that it translates network calls made by guest OS to the host OS system calls" I wouldn't assume that; VMware isn't Wine, it's a program that emulates a PC on which you run a full guest operating system which runs your guest applications. VMware Fusion uses BPF on OS X to emulate a network adapter; my guess is that it uses either PF_PACKET sockets or a special driver for that purpose on Linux.